# Enabling R8 in android kotlin app cause Library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-r8

I enabled R8 plugging for obfuscation

I got an exception when I am trying to generate the signed apk

```
"Library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser"
```

I have added below proGuard rule to the proguard-rules.pro file

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

and My release build specification

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Help to fix this issue

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this issue?

Comment: @Sean, I have added  -keep class org.xmlpull.v1.* {*;} this alone to my proguard rule

Comment: Is there any solution on this issue?

Answer (score 9):

**Add these lines in proguard-rules file:**

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn org.kxml2.io.**
-dontwarn android.content.res.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

**Am 100% sure these lines will resolve your issue.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you so much 

Answer (score 7):

gradle.properties

```
android.enableR8.fullMode=false
```

Comment: That and only that actually helped me. The problem occurred after I updated to Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.0. Reason: [With Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.0 the default changed from false to true](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes#default-changes)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I have the same issue and adding these lines, mentioned by the question poster to my proguard-rules.pro solved it :

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```